# Dataframes of unequal length result in merge to introduce invalid values due to nearest datetime

Tags: r, datetime, join, merge, data.table

I merged two dataframes, ~251k rows and ~237k rows, respectively, based on nearest datetime. However, I have an issue with the output.

Here are small, hypothetical examples.

Large dataframe:

`dflarge <- data.frame(datetime  = c("2021-01-01 12:47:16", "2021-01-01 13:47:16", "2021-01-01 14:47:16", "2021-01-01 15:47:16", "2021-01-01 16:47:16"))`

Converting to datetime format:

`dflarge$datetime <- as.POSIXct(dflarge$datetime)`

`tibble(dflarge)`

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  datetime           
  <dttm>             
1 2021-01-01 12:47:16
2 2021-01-01 13:47:16
3 2021-01-01 14:47:16
4 2021-01-01 15:47:16
5 2021-01-01 16:47:16
```

Small dataframe and necessary format conversions:

`dfsmall <- data.frame(datetime  = c("2021-01-01 15:00:00", "2021-01-01 16:00:00", "2021-01-01 17:00:00"), value = c("0.5", "1.0", "1.5"))`

`dfsmall$datetime <- as.POSIXct(dfsmall$datetime)`

`dfsmall$value <- as.numeric(dfsmall$value)`

`tibble(dfsmall)`

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  datetime              value
  <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2021-01-01 15:00:00   0.5
2 2021-01-01 16:00:00   1  
3 2021-01-01 17:00:00   1.5
```

Now I perform the merge...

`library(data.table)`

`setDT(dflarge)[, value := setDT(dfsmall)[dflarge, value, on = "datetime", roll = "nearest"]]`

`tibble(dflarge)`

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  datetime              value
  <dttm>              <dbl>
1 2021-01-01 12:47:16   0.5
2 2021-01-01 13:47:16   0.5
3 2021-01-01 14:47:16   0.5
4 2021-01-01 15:47:16   1  
5 2021-01-01 16:47:16   1.5
```

Despite the logic behind the result, as you can see the first two records have also had the value `0.5` assigned to it but this is incorrect!

To remove or modify these values manually will not suffice i.e., scrolling through 1/4 million records and finding where the duplications start. The scripts I am compiling is for autonomous database merging and appending.

I basically require a function that only matches the `dfshort$value` to a `dflarge$datetime` that is around e.g., the nearest 1 hour of `dfshort$datetime`, not >= 2 hours apart AND, subsequently replace irrelevant values with `NA` or `NAN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burrowing ideas from a solution to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379863/join-two-data-tables-on-date-with-closest-date-in-table-1-strictly-less-than-da):

```
setDT(dflarge)
setDT(dfsmall)
dflarge[, joindatetime := datetime + 3600] # we add 3600 secs (one hour)
dflarge[, value := dfsmall[dflarge, value, on = .(datetime = joindatetime), roll = 7200]
        ][, joindatetime := NULL]
#               datetime value
# 1: 2021-01-01 12:47:16  <NA>
# 2: 2021-01-01 13:47:16  <NA>
# 3: 2021-01-01 14:47:16   0.5
# 4: 2021-01-01 15:47:16   1.0
# 5: 2021-01-01 16:47:16   1.5
```

Comment: Thanks @sindri_baldur, such genius is priceless!

Re., searching for solutions, the issue is what keywords to search for and thus finding solutions remain an issue for less advanced users on this platform.